# powershell add column to existing csv file with Mailbox property

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm currently running a script that obtains a list of Exchange Online mailboxes from a CSV file, and converts them to Shared Mailboxes. I then have the script waiting for a period of time, before looping through the CSV again and extracting the type of Mailbox it is. It's a check to confirm that the mailbox has actually converted successfully. Finally, I want it to add a new column to the CSV file with the mailbox type.

Currently, it all seems to work correctly, except writing back to the CSV. The CSV ends up blank.

```
$SMTP = import-csv -Path .\Convert.csv | & {
    process {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.FullAddress -Type Shared -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $True -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled $True -ErrorAction Continue -WarningAction Continue
    }
    
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    
$SMTP = import-csv -Path .\Convert.csv | & {
    process {
        $MBType = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $_.FullAddress | Select RecipientTypeDetails
        Select-Object *,@{Name='Type';Expression={$MBType}} |
    
        Export-CSV -Path .\Convert.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Initially I thought it's because it can't write to a file that is open, but when exporting to a new CSV, the result is still a blank file.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
(Import-Csv .\Convert.csv) | 
  Select-Object *, 
                @{
                  Name = 'Type'
                  Expression = { (Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $_.FullAddress).RecipientTypeDetails } 
                } |
  Export-CSV -Path .\Convert.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

- `(...)` around the `Import-Csv` call ensures that the input file is read in full into memory first, which is the prerequisite for writing back to the same file in the same pipeline.

  - That said, if you change your first pipeline to `($SMTP = import-csv -Path .\Convert.csv) | ...`, you can use `$SMTP` as the input to your second one, in lieu of `(Import-Csv .\Convert.csv)`
- You can pipe directly to `Select-Object` with the added [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your `Select-Object` call is missing *input*, which should have been: `$_ | Select-Object ...` in order to process the input object at hand (as reflected in [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)).
- Without input, `Select-Object` produces *no output*, and therefore `Export-Csv` produced an *empty file*.

  - Aside from that, the `Export-Csv` should be in a *subsequent* pipeline segment, so as to receive *all* objects to write to the file, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. Your code block worked. I had tried putting brackets around both instances of `$SMTP = import-csv -Path .\Convert.csv` to ensure the file gets closed, but it kept telling me that identity was null.

I've left the first instance intact, as I'm assuming the file is closed at the end of the scriptblock, just before the `Start-Sleep` occurs. Then used your code for the second instance of importing the CSV and that's worked well.

Comment: Yes, when a pipeline ends, the file is closed. You can do `($SMTP = import-csv -Path .\Convert.csv) | ...` as the first pipeline, which means that you can use`$SMTP` in the second pipeliine as input, instead of having to call `Import-Csv` again, i.e. `$SMP | Select-Object ...`